# Создать функцию, которая будет запускать др. функцию заданное количество раз и возвращать массив с результатами вызовов

Tags: javascript, функции

коллеги! Я совсем недавно изучаю JS и вот добрался до темы замыкание функций... Прошу вашей помощи :)

Есть функция sequence, которая увеличивает значение start на step каждый раз при запуске. С ней все ок.

```
function sequence(start = 0, step = 1) {
    var result = start;
    return function () {
        result = start;
        start += step;
        return result;
    };
};
```

Задача написать функцию take(gen, x), которая будет запускать функцию sequence заданное количество раз и возвращать массив с результатами вызовов.

```
function take (gen, x) {
    // Код который нужно написать...
}

var gen1 = sequence(0, 2);
console.log(take(gen1, 5)); // [0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
```

Думаю, для эксперта в вопросе это решение покажется очень простым (мне вряд ли...))), поэтому буду очень благодарен, если дадите небольшой комментарий как работает ваше решение, т.к. для меня главное это понять принцип работы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В Вашем случае первым аргументом (`gen1`) передаётся функция, которую просто следует вызвать необходимое количество раз в цикле и записать результат её выполнения в массив.

```js
function sequence(start = 0, step = 1) {
    var result = start;
    return function () {
        result = start;
        start += step;
        return result;
    };
};

function take (gen, x) {
  let data = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < x; i += 1)
      data.push(gen());
      
  return data;
}

console.log(take(sequence(0, 2), 5));
console.log(take(sequence(0, 2), 6));
console.log(take(sequence(0, 5), 4));
```